# When is the central singular fiber $X_0$ of a proper map $X \to D$ a deformation retract of $X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, and $f:X \to D$ a proper map with connected fibers to the unit disc $D \subset \mathbb C$. Assume that $f$ is submersive (algebro-geometric lingo: smooth) over $D^* = D \setminus \{0\}$.

Under which conditions (possibly after shrinking $D$) can I say that the central fiber $X_0 = f^{-1}(0)$ is a deformation retract of $X$?

If $X_0$ is smooth, this follows easily by Ehresmann's theorem.

Yesterday I thought I found a reference in Voisin's *Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry II*, that this works if $f$ has only isolated critical points. But today I can't find that anymore. Is it true anyway? Is it true in more general settings?

*Motivation*. This is one of the starting assumptions when reading about the formalism of vanishing cycles in *Le formalisme des cycles évanescents*, SGA 7-2 by Deligne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was also posted on [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264940/proper-family-deformation-retracts-onto-special-fiber), where one finds references (though I didn't really find a clean statement in the references).

In the comments of that question, there is also the following argument using gradient descent: Choose a Riemannian metric $g$ on $X$, and consider the vector field
$$\nabla |f|^2 = \hat g^{-1}(d|f|^2),$$
where $\hat g: TX \to T^*X, v \mapsto g(v,-)$  is the identification given by $g$. For any $p \in X$ the vector $f_* \nabla|f|^2_p$ is a multiple of $$\begin{pmatrix}x(f(p)) \\ y(f(p))\end{pmatrix}$$ where $x,y$ are the real coordinates on $D$, since that is the direction in which $|f|^2$ increases the most. By the escape lemma, the flow associated to $- \nabla|f|^2$ is a total flow $\Phi: \mathbb R \times X \to X$, because all integral curves approach $X_0$, hence they cannot escape. Choosing a reparametrization $\varphi: [0,1) \to \mathbb R_{\geq0}$ to obtain a retract
$$\Psi:[0,1] \times X \to X, \quad \Psi(t,p) = \Phi(\varphi(t),p).$$
For $t=1$ we take the limit of the corresponding integral curve, which exists because $f:X \to D$ is proper.